# Undefined reference to `freenect_sync_get_depth'

Tags: openkinect

I am trying to compile this program to generate point cloud using kinect on Ubuntu 14.04

```cpp
 /*
 * This file is part of the OpenKinect Project. http://www.openkinect.org
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2010 individual OpenKinect contributors. See the CONTRIB file
 * for details.
 *
 * Andrew Miller <amiller@dappervision.com>
 *
 * This code is licensed to you under the terms of the Apache License, version
 * 2.0, or, at your option, the terms of the GNU General Public License,
 * version 2.0. See the APACHE20 and GPL2 files for the text of the licenses,
 * or the following URLs:
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.txt
 *
 * If you redistribute this file in source form, modified or unmodified, you
 * may:
 *   1) Leave this header intact and distribute it under the same terms,
 *      accompanying it with the APACHE20 and GPL20 files, or
 *   2) Delete the Apache 2.0 clause and accompany it with the GPL2 file, or
 *   3) Delete the GPL v2 clause and accompany it with the APACHE20 file
 * In all cases you must keep the copyright notice intact and include a copy
 * of the CONTRIB file.
 *
 * Binary distributions must follow the binary distribution requirements of
 * either License.
 */

#include "libfreenect.h"
#include "libfreenect_sync.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#if defined(__APPLE__)
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

int window;
GLuint gl_rgb_tex;
int mx=-1,my=-1;        // Prevous mouse coordinates
int rotangles[2] = {0}; // Panning angles
float zoom = 1;         // zoom factor
int color = 1;          // Use the RGB texture or just draw it as color

// Do the projection from u,v,depth to X,Y,Z directly in an opengl matrix
// These numbers come from a combination of the ros kinect_node wiki, and
// nicolas burrus' posts.
void LoadVertexMatrix()
{
    float fx = 594.21f;
    float fy = 591.04f;
    float a = -0.0030711f;
    float b = 3.3309495f;
    float cx = 339.5f;
    float cy = 242.7f;
    GLfloat mat[16] = {
        1/fx,     0,  0, 0,
        0,    -1/fy,  0, 0,
        0,       0,  0, a,
        -cx/fx, cy/fy, -1, b
    };
    glMultMatrixf(mat);
}


// This matrix comes from a combination of nicolas burrus's calibration post
// and some python code I haven't documented yet.
void LoadRGBMatrix()
{
    float mat[16] = {
        5.34866271e+02,   3.89654806e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   1.74704200e-02,
        -4.70724694e+00,  -5.28843603e+02,   0.00000000e+00,  -1.22753400e-02,
        -3.19670762e+02,  -2.60999685e+02,   0.00000000e+00,  -9.99772000e-01,
        -6.98445586e+00,   3.31139785e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   1.09167360e-02
    };
    glMultMatrixf(mat);
}

void mouseMoved(int x, int y)
{
    if (mx>=0 && my>=0) {
        rotangles[0] += y-my;
        rotangles[1] += x-mx;
    }
    mx = x;
    my = y;
}

void mousePress(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN) {
        mx = x;
        my = y;
    }
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_UP) {
        mx = -1;
        my = -1;
    }
}

void no_kinect_quit(void)
{
    printf("Error: Kinect not connected?\n");
    exit(1);
}

void DrawGLScene()
{
    short *depth = 0;
    char *rgb = 0;
    uint32_t ts;
    if (freenect_sync_get_depth((void**)&depth, &ts, 0, FREENECT_DEPTH_11BIT) < 0)
    no_kinect_quit();
    if (freenect_sync_get_video((void**)&rgb, &ts, 0, FREENECT_VIDEO_RGB) < 0)
    no_kinect_quit();

    static unsigned int indices[480][640];
    static short xyz[480][640][3];
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < 480; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 640; j++) {
            xyz[i][j][0] = j;
            xyz[i][j][1] = i;
            xyz[i][j][2] = depth[i*640+j];
            indices[i][j] = i*640+j;
        }
    }

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glPushMatrix();
    glScalef(zoom,zoom,1);
    glTranslatef(0,0,-3.5);
    glRotatef(rotangles[0], 1,0,0);
    glRotatef(rotangles[1], 0,1,0);
    glTranslatef(0,0,1.5);

    LoadVertexMatrix();

    // Set the projection from the XYZ to the texture image
    glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glScalef(1/640.0f,1/480.0f,1);
    LoadRGBMatrix();
    LoadVertexMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glPointSize(1);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_SHORT, 0, xyz);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glTexCoordPointer(3, GL_SHORT, 0, xyz);

    if (color)
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl_rgb_tex);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, 640, 480, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, rgb);

    glPointSize(2.0f);
    glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, 640*480, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices);
    glPopMatrix();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void keyPressed(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    if (key == 27) {
        freenect_sync_stop();
        glutDestroyWindow(window);
        exit(0);
    }
    if (key == 'w')
        zoom *= 1.1f;
    if (key == 's')
        zoom /= 1.1f;
    if (key == 'c')
        color = !color;
}

void ReSizeGLScene(int Width, int Height)
{
    glViewport(0,0,Width,Height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60, 4/3., 0.3, 200);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void InitGL(int Width, int Height)
{
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glGenTextures(1, &gl_rgb_tex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl_rgb_tex);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    ReSizeGLScene(Width, Height);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_ALPHA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);

    window = glutCreateWindow("LibFreenect");

    glutDisplayFunc(&DrawGLScene);
    glutIdleFunc(&DrawGLScene);
    glutReshapeFunc(&ReSizeGLScene);
    glutKeyboardFunc(&keyPressed);
    glutMotionFunc(&mouseMoved);
    glutMouseFunc(&mousePress);

    InitGL(640, 480);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

I have `libfreenect`, `opengl` installed. But the linker gives the following error. I tried

`find /usr -name *freenect*sync*`

to locate the libraries I am missing and got the following output

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreenect_sync.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreenect_sync.so.0.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreenect_sync.so.0.2.0
/usr/include/libfreenect_sync.h
```

When I tried after including this `-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, the linker produced the following error.

```
lakshayg@lakshayg:~/freenect/pclview$ make
g++ -I/usr/X11R6/include `pkg-config --cflags libfreenect` glpclview.cpp -o glpclview `pkg-config --libs libfreenect` -L/usr/X11R6/lib/  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lGL -lGLU -lglut 
/tmp/cclq9nUn.o: In function `DrawGLScene()':
glpclview.cpp:(.text+0x269): undefined reference to `freenect_sync_get_depth'
glpclview.cpp:(.text+0x28f): undefined reference to `freenect_sync_get_video'
/tmp/cclq9nUn.o: In function `keyPressed(unsigned char, int, int)':
glpclview.cpp:(.text+0x5cd): undefined reference to `freenect_sync_stop'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [glpclview] Error 1
lakshayg@lakshayg:~/freenect/pclview$
```

Here is the Makefile I am using for the code

```
FLAGS = `pkg-config --cflags libfreenect`
INCLUDE = -I/usr/X11R6/include
LIBS = `pkg-config --libs libfreenect` -L/usr/X11R6/lib/  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lGL -lGLU -lglut 

glpclview: glpclview.cpp
    g++ $(INCLUDE) $(FLAGS) $? -o $@ $(LIBS)
```

I am relatively new to linux and completely stumped at this point. What should I do so that the program compiles successfully ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out how to compile it!

`g++ glpclview.cpp -o glpclview -lfreenect -lfreenect_sync -lGL -lGLU -lglut`

I was missing the `-lfreenect_sync` flag to link the freenect sync drivers.